# Grub rescue after removing Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot

I dual booted ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Windows 8, but I wanted to get rid of ubuntu. So I got EasyBCD (on windows 8) and removed Ubuntu following a tutorial on youtube, then I got rid of the Ubuntu partitions. After restarting my Sony Vaio, it went to grub rescue and I'm not sure what to do. Help please! Much appreciated!!

I installed ubuntu using a USB.

Comment: Normaly if u removed ubuntu partions, grub won't be able to boot.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a windows installation cd and restore the bootloader on the MBR through the recovery environment or using the startup repair option under advanced settings. Here is a guide http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-fix-windows-8-mbr-master-boot-record/

Related support article: (unfortunately I could only find one for ~windows 7 but the previous guide is very straightforward)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392#method1

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Burn an Ubuntu ISO image onto a USB drive or a DVD to make a live USB/DVD.
2. Boot into live mode ("Try Ubuntu" option).
3. After it boots up, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to bring up the Terminal.
4. Put these codes ONE AFTER ANOTHER.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install boot-repair
   ```
5. After doing this, open the "Dash" (Search menu). It can be accessed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
6. Search for "Boot Repair" (Although just entering Boot will give you the app).
7. Open it and select the only option (Recommended one).
8. Reboot. You will no longer get the GRUB Error after this, and will boot straight into Windows.

**You can also do it with Ubuntu installed. In case you want to uninstall Ubuntu, first follow the above instructions, then after you are in Windows, install EaseUS Partition Manager and delete the Ubuntu partitions (the ones that are *NOT* NTFS formatted).**

Comment: Hope I help. This actually worked for me. I was having the exact same problem as you, only with Windows XP. But the Application I have mentioned first scans the PC, and then installs MBR.
So I think it should work.

Comment: And make sure you perform step 3.5: Connect to the internet.

Comment: Also, this didn't work for me.  I followed the steps exactly and I am still seeing "grub rescue" when I try to boot into Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Install again Ubuntu "alongside" of Windows 8, now entering Windows 8.

Install this software on Windows (is free): http://download.cnet.com/MiniTool-Partition-Wizard-Home-Edition/3000-2094_4-10962200.html?part=dl-6285158&subj=dl&tag=button

Run the software, right click in your disk and after in "Rebuild MBR", after click in "Apply" in top, now you can delete the partitions by Ubuntu **with that software, it's not necessary to run Ubuntu**, and after click in Apply.

Good luck!