# fixing grub after removing linux

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, mbr

I had installed Ubuntu on a friend's computer. It had two drives - C and D, so I took D (which didn't include the system) and reformatted it with Ubuntu.

After a week he has asked me to remove it. So in Windows, I used the partition manager to reformat the Ubuntu partition as a ntfs drive for windows. I then forgot about grub, and sometime later, after a restart, my friend was stuck with grub rescue.

I do not have any Windows CD at hand... What's the best way to fix this? (I've found many suggestions, but most of them fix it through ubuntu, which in this case isn't relevant because I removed Ubuntu).

Thoughts?

Comment: It really makes no sense to fix Grub after removing the distro that contains most of it - in other words, there is nothing to fix. You just need to [restore the Windows boot loader](https://www.google.co.il/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=restore+windows+bootloader&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=9YleU5PZOI6V_AakiICQDQ&gbv=1&sei=9oleU5n4Fuqm4ATf1oFw). Just search howto do it without the Windows CD.

Comment: @mikewhatever Yes. I eventually fixed it using Ultimate Boot CD

Comment: @mikewhatever also, for the record, I knew that was the problem. It was finding a solution that did not include the Windows CD that was problematic, because I couldn't find many examples and suggestions (even the one that I eventually used - the Ultimate Boot CD, didn't behave even a bit the way people suggested to use it, eventually I figured out how to solve it with it by myself. But - again, I'm a little tech-oriented, I don't know if that would be an easy solution for other people)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grub rescue after removing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/287229/grub-rescue-after-removing-ubuntu)

Comment: @user68186 if anything, it's a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on. Admittedly, I didn't find that in my initial research for a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a search on the internet for the correct version of windows that he is using and find the MSDN iso for that version.

There are links online from digital rivers for the untouched iso directly from microsoft.  burn the iso or create a usb drive. Boot from the dvd, usb and select the repair installation option.

I am not sure if I can post links on this site but if you do a google search you can find the iso you need.

Comment: Thank you. You can definitly post links (that would be great for other people with similar problems in the future), but eventually I fixed the MBR through an [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/). My solution is not a very user-friendly method and requires you to know your way around computers a little bit. Anyone who doesn't feel comfortable with messing with black screens and prompts should try Joe's answer (thus I mark it as correct)